# multiple v-for on one line

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**EDIT 1**

Here is the `script`

```
<script>
import firebase from '@/middleware/firebase'

const database = firebase.database()

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      cruises: [],
      search: '',
      paginate: ['cruises']
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    database.ref('cruises').on('child_added', snapshot => this.cruises.push(snapshot.val()))
  },
  computed: {
    filteredCruises: function () {
      var self = this;
      return this.cruises.filter(function(cruise) { 
        return cruise.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >=0;
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to paginate the filteredCruises I am using the https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate package for the pagination. So I'm just trying to merge the two if I can.

**Original Question**

Just a quick `v-for` query.

Is it possible to merge

```
<section class="shadow p-4 h-32 mb-4" v-for="cruise in paginated('cruise')" :key="cruise.id">
<section class="shadow p-4 h-32 mb-4" v-for="cruise in filteredCruises" :key="cruise.id">
```

onto one line one because I need to call the paginated as well as a computed function.

Comment: What does the `paginated` method do? I'm not a fan of using the return value from a method in `v-for` as it is aggressively computed

Answer (score 2):

Any of these:

```vue
<!-- ES6 array spread syntax -->
<section v-for="cruise in [...paginated('cruise'), ...filteredCruises]">
```

```vue
<!-- ES5 -->
<section v-for="cruise in paginated('cruise').concat(filteredCruises)">
```

You can put it into a computed property if you don't want to litter your markup with too much code.

Comment: Ok I get `Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined` https://gyazo.com/9c0e9042bf2d119134ffcb52dd271b37

Comment: That means `paginated('cruise')` is returning `undefined` instead of an empty array. Either change the `paginated` method to always return an array, or you will need to do something like `(paginated('cruise') || []).concat`.

Comment: I'm using the https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate plugin for the pagination I believe it's returning an array.

Comment: I'd have gone with a computed property (just for the cleanliness). Same logic though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to paginate the filtered cruises, or filter the paginated cruises, but solution is simple: use one `v-for`. With computed property which is doing what you need.

Edit: Improved example

```
<script>
  import firebase from '@/middleware/firebase'

  export default {
    data: _ => ({
      cruises: [],
      search: '',
      paginate: ['cruises'],
      db: firebase.database(),
      ref: this.db.ref('cruises'),
      query: this.ref.on('child_added', this.updateCruises)
    }),

    computed: {
      filteredCruises () {
        return this.cruises.filter({title} => {
          return new RegExp(this.search, 'i').test(title)
        })
      }
    },

    methods: {
      updateCruises (snapshot) {
        this.cruises.push(snapshot.val())
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<input v-model="search">

<paginate
  name="cruises"
  :list="filteredCruises"
  :per="5"
>
  <section v-for="cruise in paginated('cruises')">
    {{ cruise.title }}
  </section>
</paginate>
```

Comment: And? Still not working? And what? Filtering doesn't work? Or?